# Is there something like Webmaster's Toolkit that runs on Linux?

Tags: html, css, linux

When I'm working on HTML or CSS, I'm constantly trying to figure out "How many pixels of padding are inside this element? And what color is it? And is that left margin three pixels wide or four?"

Is there a Linux application or set of applications that magnifies part of the screen and provides a pixel ruler and color picker within that magnified space? Like the Windows application called "Webmaster's Toolkit" -- http://spicebrains.com.

Answer (score 5):

Get [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), it's indispensable.

Comment: I do use Firebug -- it can do this?

Comment: yes, inspect an element, then look on the right side for properties & metrics... or see the tutorials posted by Luis! :)

Comment: That's no help -- I need to see what the actual number of pixels between two elements is. Those pixels could come from padding, margins, or all kinds of other things. That's why I need to actually count pixels, right off the rendered page.

Answer (score 2):

There is a webdev plugin for firefox that would provide all that information.

[Web Developer](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/)

Comment: I installed WebDev, but I don't see any of the tools I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Excelent Firebug tutorials:

1. [Firebug Tutorial - Logging, Profiling and CommandLine (Part I)](http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/09/firebug-tutorial-logging-profiling-and-commandline-part-i)
2. [Firebug Tutorial - Logging,
   Profiling and CommandLine (Part II)](http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/10/firebug-tutorial-logging-profiling-and-commandline-part-ii)
3. [Firebug Tutorial - Using Commandline API in Firebug](http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/15/firebug-tutorial-commandline-api)
4. [Firebug Tutorial : Section 4 - Net, CSS and DOM tabs](http://michaelsync.net/2007/10/15/firebug-tutorial-section-4-net-css-and-dom-tabs)

**UPDATE:** This is what i'm talking about. (my firebug is in spanish but you get the idea).
And if you click where the "little" red arrow is, you'll get a nice ruler.

[alt text http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/573/pantallazogm6.png](http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/573/pantallazogm6.png)

Comment: That's no help -- I need to see what the actual number of pixels between two elements is. Those pixels could come from padding, margins, or all kinds of other things. Reading element properties won't tell me that; I need to actually look at the pixels that get rendered.

Answer (score 1):

One dead-simple way to measure pixels is to just take a screenshot and drag it into GIMP. You can get colors using the eyedropper, and dimensions using the marquee (select) tool.

Comment: Yes, that's got 100% of the functionality and is actually what i do now. It just takes about 50 times longer than a hotkey app.

Answer (score 0):

Well Web developer extension provides a pixel ruler. And you could use that in combination with the gnome accessible magnifier? I guess.

Answer (score 0):

For measuring distances on screen, have a look at `kruler` or `screenruler`.